# Why might a single texture not always render, but all others do?

Tags: rendering

When rendering an animation, I noticed that one texture did not render (purple), though it was there even in render view.  Using Eevee.  To make matters worse, I tried still renders, looking to see when/where it was happening.  The results were inconsistent.  Sometimes it would render fine.  I hit render again without changing a thing, and it would come out purple.  Anything I might be missing?  Or just flaky code?

Comment: Hello, care to share a screenshot ?

Comment: Possible GPU issue...? Try render with CPU only to see if that fixes it. Could be that the texture is failing due to GPU memory low.

Comment: How about a video demonstration?  I'm working on laptop.  CPU only.  https://youtu.be/QUNyhmBHfYY

Comment: Note:  Even when it "works" (not purple) it still isn't the texture it should be....